# Is there any way to know what values are selected in palette before you will submit a form?

Tags: java, wicket

I am trying to make an autocomplete palette and so far so good, but I i have a qestion, is there any way to know which elements are selected?

Comment: Provide some code for us to know what you have done so far

Comment: It's just a simple palette and text field with onUpdate listener. And I want to get an values, before submitting a form from that Palette.

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with a Palette, but I guess you're looking for something like this (upper part from [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/wicket-palette-example/))

```
final Palette<Hosting> palette = new Palette<Hosting>("palette",
new ListModel<T>(selected),
new CollectionModel<T>(listHosting),
renderer, 10, true);
palette.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {
@Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
       //get what you want here
    }
});
```

I'm not sure if it works this way, but in general you can add an

```
AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange")
```

to get data before submitting.

Comment: But I didn't find a way to get correct data from that, palette still has no selected values, because form is not submitted. And I am trying to find a way around this.

Comment: I think I got your question now: E.g. you want to get the value of the object on the left side onclick, before you use the Button [ > ] to submit it to the right side?

Comment: Well, yes, but it's the other way around. I can't get values from the right side, after I added them there, without submitting the whole form.